# Adding a COM Class to a setup Project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, com

I was creating a set up project for a COM class. So users can install the dll and get additional features as an option. However i labelled the COM Class so i renamed the dll. However when i changed the dll from class.dll to comclass.dll, and ran regAsm again, when i added the comclass.dll to the project the .tlb was class.tlb listed in the `Detected Dependencies` folder, keeping the old name.

So i decided to create a new project with new GUIDs to just fix it and named it comclass.dll. Everything tested and compiled but once i got to the set up portion of and added the comclass.dll, nothing was showing up in `detected dependencies` only .net framework. Before the old .dll use to get the .tlb to show up. Now i can't get the .tlb to show up.

If i add the .tlb directly to the project it gives an error at set up time regarding the setup not being able to register the .tlb file.

Comment: This is normal, hard to guess how you got it to show up before.  Right-click the Setup project, Add, File and select the .tlb

Comment: ah ok, but when i tried to set it up to register as a com i got an error while running my setup file.